# IntelliJ Editor keyboard issues

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am new to IntelliJ, and am having way too many problems with the editor. For example:

I expect Shift + Up to select text going up, or Shift + left to select text going left, but its just moving the cursor position without selection..

A lot of errors for example "function User(){" when I press enter I expect the other closing curly bracket to go down, sometimes it does, sometimes it just gives an error sound and doesn't do anything...

I am having the same issues even after closing and opening it again, is there a way to fix all these issues and just have normal keyboard keys like in other IDEs?

Comment: Nobody else has these issues and you haven't given anything like enough information to work out what's going on. Try starting with your OS and the keymappings you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keymap in the settings.